# Add class to image field

Tags: 7, media

I'm looking for a way to add a class field to Drupal's image field (field_image). At the moment my images are displayed using code like this:

```
<img alt="Alternate text here" src="/path/to/image" />
```

I'd like to add a class field so that the code would be like so:

```
<img alt="Alternate text here" class="portrait floatLeft" src="/path/to/image" />
```

I think I could achieve this by adding a field to the content type to store the class name - I could then use views to add the class value to the image's parent DIV. However, I suspect there's a way to add a class field to the image field itself - it's not uncommon for images to have classes ;)

I've tried the [File Entity](https://www.drupal.org/node/1591498) module, which according to the documentation allows you to create custom file types. Sadly it doesn't explain how.

Any pointers / suggestions would be much appreciated.

**Edit:** To clarify, I'd like to be able to add classes on a per image basis. Some images might need the classes *portrait floatLeft*, others might need *landscape floatNone* and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

Consider looking at the [Image Class](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_class) module, which extends the Image formatter by adding an option to add an element class.

It requires the [Field formatter settings](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_formatter_settings) module (dependency).

Comment: Thanks, I had looked into that module. It allows you to add the same class to all images (defined on the Manage display tab), which is not what I'm after. I want to be able to define a class when adding an image (they won't all have the same class).

Comment: @rkhff I don't believe classes will follow an image, so you would have to determine the class when it was output, not when it was added, or create a custom module to track images and the optional classes they posses